# populate dropdown from a column of a table in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application I want to make a dropdown that populates a column of a table:

```
having the table:

id | openings  | location
1  | developer | abc
2  | engineer  | mno
```

and I want to populate dropdown from `openings` into the table: and below

```
<div class="opening1">
  <%= select :select_opening, options_from_collection_for_select(@openings,"id","openings"), {}, :id => "DDL_Openings", :style => "margin-top: 10px" %>
</div>
```

But I am getting error below:

```
 wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
```

Below is controller page:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @openings = Opening.all
  end

  def openings
    @getopening = Opening.select('"OpeningTitle", "OpeningLocation", "OpeningDescription"' )
  end

  def viewresume
    @openings = Opening.all
  end

end

end
```

And at this line `@openings = Opening.all` get all columns of the `opening` table and I want to get values of `OpeningTitle` column of the table for populating dropdown.
Kindly help me, waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: `@veterans` object value?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag might help in your case.

Comment: Can you post the related controller code?

Comment: The view file belongs to which action?

Comment: What happens when you change it to `<%= select :select_opening, options_from_collection_for_select(@openings,"id","openings"), {}, :id => "DDL_Openings", :style => "margin-top: 10px" %>`

Comment: what values do you want to have in the dropdown? Am I right assuming: `['developer', 'engineer', ...]`?

Comment: @Pavan: but it gets me error `wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)`